# Fdroid OTP Authenticator, how to move accounts to new phone?

Tags: google-authenticator, f-droid

This is NOT the Google enabled Authenticator. This is https://f-droid.org/en/packages/net.bierbaumer.otp_authenticator/

There is no signing in.

Is there anyway to move credentials / accounts over to another phone? At worst, it seems like you need to just re-add them to your new phone, but maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app doesn't offer any feature to do this, as you can see from the [issue log](https://github.com/0xbb/otp-authenticator/issues/18). That leaves with two choices

- Using backup methods for only an app as discussed here [Full Backup of non-rooted devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28296/131553)
- If your  device is already rooted, using [titanium-backup](/questions/tagged/titanium-backup) is a popular choice (amongst other such apps)

But I suspect your device is not rooted, so you have only one choice